# Using Ischanged in a workflow rule

Tags: workflow

I am trying to create a workflow rule that sends an email to our licensing group anytime a contact record goes from inactive, back to active.

In my rule criteria, can I use `ISCHANGED()` and have it only trigger when `Active__c` goes from `false` to `true` but not when it goes from `true` to `false`?

Comment: What is your WF criteria, Ischanged can be used only when you set created and every time it's edited on a workflow rule.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `ISCHANGED()` in a workflow rule where the Evaluation Criteria is set to "Created", or "Created, and every time it's edited". Trying to use this function in a workflow with the Evaluation Criteria of "Created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria" will net you the below error:

> Function ISCHANGED may not be used in this type of formula

However, `ISCHANGED()` will only provide a Boolean value if the field has changed. To get the previous value of the field, you'll have to use `PRIORVALUE()`, which you can use in your formula to check if a field has switch from one value to another.

For example, both the answer by @markross__c, and your eventual solution will work.

```
AND (
    ISCHANGED(Active__c),
    Active__c == true
)

AND (
    PRIORVALUE(Active__c) == false,
    Active__c == true
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this! Your workflow rule should look like this:
ISCHANGED(Active__c) &&
Active__c = TRUE

Comment: Using the formula above I get the following error:  Error: Function ISCHANGED may not be used in this type of formula

Comment: I ended up using:  Active__c = True&&
PRIORVALUE(Active__c)=False  Thank you for heading me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use a combination of isChanged() and PriorValue(). PriorValue() will help you to find which was the previous value.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This is what I ended up with:  Active__c = True&&
PRIORVALUE(Active__c)=False

Comment: Good that is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write  it on this way.

In Workflow Rule :

```
AND (
ISCHANGED(Active__c),
IF( Active__c, false, true) 
)
```

Explanation :

Here if "Active__c" is changed and true then i will retun it as

false and when it is false then it retun true and your operation will perform.